# How to make a TypeVar (Generic) type in python with dataclass constraint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, typing

Is there a way to constraint some TypeVar to be dataclass? for example something like:

```
A = TypeVar('A', dataclass) # Wrong code!
```

Comment: I faced the same problem. The question is why you want to know it is a dataclass? Every class object has  properties. So if you want to know it is a dataclass because you want to use the dataclass API, i.e. getting a list of all fields, then you could define a protocol for this. Tell me you use case and I will try to write the protocol as answer.

Comment: Or do you actually want to tell the reader/the Typing Tool -> this is only data, it is not a class with functions?